# Reset column reorder and colvis in one button

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using Datatables Jquery library and use the ColReorder and Colvis functionality. Currently there is a way to reset the column reordering namely

`table.colReorder.reset();`

And colvis reset is done by adding "Show All" in the setting ,like so

```
 colVis = {
    showAll: "Restore Defaults"
};
```

Is there a way , I can combine these two functionalities into a single button click? Eg:

```
$("#restore_defaults").click(function(){
   // reset colorder
//reset column visibility
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reseting ColReorder is straightforward. But there is no public API to change the visibility for ColVis.

```
// this is to reset ColReorder
table.colReorder.reset();
```

**Implement Column Visibility:**

[Change visibility of each column manually](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible()) and use [fnRebuild](https://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/api) to re-render the checkboxes in the ColVis dropdown because the visibility has changed and so should the checkboxes.

```
// change visibility of columns
table.columns().visible( true, true );
// re-render the buttons in ColVis button dropdown
$.fn.dataTable.ColVis.fnRebuild( table );
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/24/**

Comment: The second option has an issue. when you reload the page . The $('.ColVis_ShowAll') is not present at all and hence would not work.

Comment: That's weird. Thanks for letting me know. Well, the first option will definitely work :-)

Comment: The first seems to be a good idea. I needed a way to make the checkboxes work . Good job on finding the fnRebuild function. Option 1 works fine ! Option 2 does not work (that is what i did initially).Thanks very much for the help . Accepting Option 1.

Comment: Yeah since the show_all button is within show/hide master button . The show_all is initialised only when u click the master button .

Comment: oh yeah that does make sense.